# Icons on the panel and launcher are the wrong color

Tags: 11.04, icons, support

I have an icon problem with Ubuntu Natty: the ones on the panel are all black; the icons on the launcher have some color, but aren't all the right icons. It has been this way since I installed Natty.

Every once in awhile when I start the computer I have nice colored icons on the panel and the launcher. I have two editor icons on the launcher, and they both will usually have the same icon, but when the colored icons are on the panel the editor icons are different, as they should be.

Can someone tell me how to keep the proper icons at boot time?

Comment: A screenshot would really help here.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you have to change theme and that will solve your problem. Black panel icons are usually used for light colored panels. The icons in the launcher depend on the theme you are using. To change it right click on the desktop, choose "Change Desktop" then click on tab with Theme. There is a button which will allow you to change icons scheme.

[image]